# How to follow the DRY principle in django when each view needs to deal with a different model?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, dry

I tried to choose a good

I have several pages with one form each. I have had to create a view for each of these pages (about 20 different pages), but the code is almost similiar. I don't see any way to cut down on repeating code on this as the different views all have to deal with a different ModelForm instance.

Example could would be for one view:

```
def portfolio_dividend_new(request, profile_id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
    post_req = False

    if request.POST:
        form = DividendForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        post_req = True

    form = DividendForm()
    return render(request, 'plan/portfolio/new_dividend.html',
                  {'form': form,
                   'profile': profile,
                   'post_req': post_req}
                  )
```

Example of another view:

```
def portfolio_buyback_new(request, profile_id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
    post_req = False

    if request.POST:
        form = SharebuybackForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        post_req = True

    form = SharebuybackForm()
    return render(request, 'plan/portfolio/new_buyback.html',
                  {'form': form,
                   'profile': profile,
                   'post_req': post_req}
                  )
```

As you can see these views have much of the same code but since they have to instantiate different ModelForm instances I dont see how to keep them from becoming two views. This wouldnt be a problem if it only were two views but its becoming like 20 views which is not maintainable anymore.

How can I avoid violating the DRY principle when I have to work with different modelforms in each view ? I dont see CBV as any better solution here as the code itself isnt very long at all and its simple enough, but the problem is that much of the code repeats itself.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Well the code in a class-based view is not long either. The idea of CBVs is not to reduce the amount of coding, but to automate the boring stuff.

Comment: Using CBVs would probably be a bit cleaner, but the main issue here is how to deal with all the repeating code. Like if I have to add or change something that is relevant for all the forms I would have to change all 20 views instead of having one function or something similar that would seem like a more correct solution...at least according to the DRY principle.

Comment: no, you simply write a base-view that handles the logic, and you use certain attributes that fill in the variable parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the differences parameters and use `functools.partial` to partially apply them.

```
from functools import partial

def portfolio_page(model, the_url, request, profile_id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
    post_req = False

    if request.POST:
        form = model(request.POST)
        form.save()
        post_req = True

    form = model()
    return render(request, the_url,
                  {'form': form,
                   'profile': profile,
                   'post_req': post_req}
                  )

portfolio_dividend_new = partial(
    portfolio_page, DividendForm, 'plan/portfolio/new_dividend.html')

portfolio_buyback_new = partial(
    portfolio_page, SharebuybackForm, 'plan/portfolio/new_buyback.html')
```

Or something like that. You only gave two examples. You could possibly pull out even more similarities, like the `'plan/portfolio/{}.html'.format(the_file)` if they're all the same. Or it might take more parameters if they differ in more places.

---

You can even partial your partial if you use it a lot, like

```
page = partial(partial, portfolio_page)

portfolio_dividend_new = page(DividendForm, 'new_dividend')
portfolio_buyback_new = page(SharebuybackForm, 'new_buyback')
foopage = page(FooModel, 'foo')
barpage = page(BarModel, 'bar')
# etc.
```

---

> I did not know you could use the "model" in that statement as a variable.

Classes are just another type of object in Python (as are functions), so you can assign them to variables and pass them as parameters to other functions, etc.

Comment: The views adding content are the same. I have thought about a similar solution like the one you posted, but the problem I have been having with that was how to get the "form = model(request.POST)" line to work as I did not know you could use the "model" in that statement as a variable. Interesting, I will check it and try it out. It would make the code a lot easier to maintain. Didnt know about the functools and partial and will check those out as well...